# Property 'axios' does not exist on type

Tags: vue.js, axios

It's my first time trying to use Vue and I've run into some troubles with axios. I have installed and imported it as per instructions on the website.
But when I'm trying to use it, I'm getting an error

> TS2339: Property 'axios' does not exist on type 'TodoList'.

Here's my main.ts

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus'
import 'element-plus/dist/index.css'

createApp(App).use(VueAxios, axios).use(ElementPlus).mount('#app')
```

And the TodoList with which I have a problem

```
<template>
    <h1>Todo List</h1>
    <todo-form @send-message="createTodo"></todo-form>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { ElMessage } from 'element-plus';
import { Options, Vue } from 'vue-class-component';
import TodoForm from './TodoForm.vue'

@Options({
    components: {
        TodoForm,
    }
})

export default class TodoList extends Vue {
    todos = [];

    async mounted() {
        await this.loadTodos();
    }

    async loadTodos() {
        const response = await this.axios.get('http://localhost:8080/');
        this.todos = response.data;
    }

    async createTodo(todo: any) {
        console.log("Todo", todo)
        ElMessage({
            message: "Todo Created",
            type: "success"
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that axios should be installed directly in application folder. Problem solved :)